# Why won't this <ul> display in my Angular/Laravel project?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

I am hoping this is something really silly (and if so, thanks and sorry!) but I am stumped by this.

I am trying to use the example here - http://jsfiddle.net/sp6bL/ to create a drop down menu in my Angular project that has submenus.

I have added this to my view;

```
<div class="menu">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
   <li ng-repeat="item in items" 
       ng-class="{'dropdown-submenu': item.submenu && item.submenu.length}">        
        <a href="@{{ item.link }}">@{{item.name}}</a>
       <ul ng-if="item.submenu && item.submenu.length" 
           class="dropdown-menu">
         <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.submenu">
           <a href="@{{subitem.link}}">@{{subitem.name}}</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And this in my controller;

```
   $scope.items = [
    {
        name: "Menu Item 1",
        link: "#main1",
        submenu: null
    },
    {
        name: "Menu Item 2",
        link: "#main2",
        submenu: null
    },
    {
        name: "Menu Item 3",
        link: "#main3",
        submenu: [
            {
                name: "Sub Item 1",
                link: "#sub1"
            },
            {
                name: "Sub Item 2",
                link: "#sub2"
            }
        ]
    }
    ];
```

Nothing renders on page and no errors.  When I view the page source from the browser I get this;

```
<div class="menu">
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
     <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'dropdown-submenu': item.submenu && item.submenu.length}"><a href="{{ item.link }}">{{item.name}}</a>
    <ul ng-if="item.submenu && item.submenu.length" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.submenu"><a href="{{subitem.link}}">{{subitem.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

But if I view the Elements in Chrome Dev Tools, I can see the ng-repeat executing.  However, nothing shows.

Huh?

**EDIT:**  Css style for dropdown-menu was set to none in one of my css files.  My over sight.

Comment: Have you added an `ng-app="myApp"` and `ng-controller="myController"`?

Comment: Just copied over your code and looks like it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/602pjq3m/

Comment: @devqon, yes I have earlier in code.  Agreed, the code seems to work there and in the original plunk but no dice in my project - that's what i am stumped on.

Comment: Does your console have any errors?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaagh!  DUMB.  My over sight.  display for the dropdown-menu style in one of my css files was set to none.  More sleep required...thanks to all for having a look.